# Is there a simple way to filter out items that don't share a common item between columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two datasets that I merged together by date. These datasets had an Id column as well. This merge created Id.x and Id.y. My question is how to filter out any rows where Id.x and Id.y don't equal one another.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: How about merging by both `date` and `id`: `merge(df1, df2, by= c("id", "date"), all.x= T)`. Use either all.x= T if you want to keep only the ids in df1 or all.y=T if you want to keep only the ids in df2

Comment: `subset(merged_data, Id.x == Id.y)`